# How to find out the file name name in Spark Streaming using fileStream() in scala?

Tags: scala, filenames, filestream, spark-streaming

I was looking all over the place how to find the name of each file that Spark Streaming picks up in the fileStream() method. There are some partial solutions in Java but I couldn't find a Scala example. There are also non-complete recommendations using FileInputFormat which is not clear how to use. Any Scala sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved this by locating and combining a number of answers to similar questions:

```
def fileNameFilter(path: Path): Boolean = {
    if (path.getName().contains("COPYING")) {
        logger.info("*** ignoring incomplete file: " + path.getName())
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

def deleteFile(sc: SparkContext, fileName: String): Unit = {
    val filePath = new Path(fileName)
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    if (fs.isDirectory(filePath)) {
        fs.listStatus(filePath).foreach((status) => {
            fs.delete(status.getPath(), true)
        })
    } else {
        fs.delete(filePath, true)
    }
}

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
val mfStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable,Text,TextInputFormat](pathToMyFiles, x=>fileNameFilter(x), true)
mfStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
....some business logic
if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
   regExp.findAllMatchIn(rdd.toDebugString).foreach(name => {
   logger.info("Deleting processed File(s): " + name.toString)
   deleteFile(sc, name.toString)
})
}

})
```

Hope this will help others with similar needs...